# Invoking an event from an extension class without passing the event

Tags: c#, events, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to simplify an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation without using a base class.  The best I've come up with is this extension method:

```
public static bool SetNotify<T>(
    this INotifyPropertyChanged sender, 
    ref T storage,
    T value, 
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, 
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Equals(storage, value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    storage = value;
    handler?.Invoke(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    return true;
}
```

This way I can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a class, declare a `PropertChangedEventHandler` event handler, and use it to trigger an event like so:

```
this.SetNotify(ref _name, value, PropertyChanged);
```

But I'm curious to know if it's possible to fire an event in a `SetNotify()` extension method to `this`, while *not* passing the event handler.  Seeing as the event handler is public, it's accessible from outside the object.  So why isn't this allowed?

```
public static bool SetNotify2<T>(
    this INotifyPropertyChanged sender,
    ref T storage,
    T value,
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Equals(storage, value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = sender.PropertyChanged;  // <-- Not allowed
    storage = value;
    handler?.Invoke(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you implement your own interface, that has a public `NotifyOnChange(string propertyName)` method, and simply call that one instead of messing with the event handlers?

Comment: How?  If implementing a `IFancyNotifyPropertyChanged` interface in every class triggering notifications, I have to add the `NotifyOnChange()` method also...?  The whole point was to simplify this without using a base class.

Comment: But are you really simplifying things? doesn't this mean that every property set method has this call to your extension method? I don't see this as a valid trade off, you might as well just create some proxies that automatically implement the INotifyPropertyChanged so you don't have to do it at all anymore (which is actually easier than it sounds, though you might have to mark your props as virtual then)

Comment: Yes, every property setter calls the method like described above.  But this isn't that big a difference from `SetNotify(ref _backingField, value);` as I do it now.  This way I at least avoid using the base class.

But can you please add a code sample of what you're suggesting?  I'm intrigued. :-)

Comment: Guess we will have to wait for [default interface methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md)...

Comment: @Oystein You can find the [full code here](https://grahammurray.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/dynamically-generating-types-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged/), I had to implement something similar not to long ago, and based lots of my code on it.

Comment: @Icepickle Yowsa! Good thing we're in the mindset of simplification here... :-D  But interesting approach.  I'll try it out on my next application.

Comment: @Oystein well, in the end, it can be more simple :) At least, from on then your proxygenerator would take over all the work, you would just make sure the properties are virtual that trigger the INotifyPropertyChanged method. I actually implemented this together with auto properties and initializing all `IList<>` with `ObservableCollections` in the constructor so I had an almost automatic support for the `INotifyCollectionChanged` events ;)